# Missing Civicrm

Tags: wordpress

Recently, I went back to WordPress and I was surprised to see CIVICRM Installer on the system.  I never delete or disable this.  I am not sure what was happening.  I checked the database and I saw the data is still there.   It seem the link between WP and CIVICRM is broken.  What would be the best approach to restore rather than reinstall and make a copy to database.

I have another question.   If I split two databases (one for WP and One for CIVICRM), will this speed up?  I tried to do this but the CIVICRM installer won't let me do this when I installed despite I typed another database name using my account.  After I clicked, it went back to WP database information and there was no way.  I could not find a script to instruct link between WP and CIVICRM

Thanks.  I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! The way this works is that multiple people can share their answers with you, and hopefully someone will ahve hte answer to your question. I recommend you split this into 2 separate questions, since each question will have it's own distinct answer and different people may have the answers to each.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a lot of useful data, I'd suggest to drop the civicrm tables and start fresh, trying to find out what happened and where whatever happened left things in slightly broken state isn't worthwhile the investigative work, download the latest version of civi and start clean

As for having separate databases, it's probably worthwhile if you have a lot of contacts or activities, not so much for speed than for backup restore convenience. but if you have a medium size installation (say less than 30k contacts), I wouldn't bother and put everything in the same database

X+